# Add layers of data in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is probably a very naive question, but I can't find clear instructions how to do this. What I am trying to do in matplotlib is:

1. Do some calculations
2. Create a figure or an axis object?
3. Add data to the object, plot it
4. Do some more calculations
5. Add new data to the object as a new layer (not extend existing data, but have a new line/scatter)

I want to do something like:

```
x = rand(10)
y = rand(10)
p = plot(x,y, '.', label="x:y")

# other code, possibly a new cell in the notebook

a = rand(10)
b = rand(10)

p.plot(a,b, '--', label="a:b") # error. what do I do to add a layer here?
```

The final plot should contain both (x,y) and (a,b) data.

I am NOT interested in having a bunch of subplots (every example seems to have those) and I want to do the above in the pylab plot (in an IPython notebook).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that what `plot` returns isn't the actual object where things are being plotted, but that's what you're trying to use it as.  So you need to define p to actually be the object you want to plot things in.

```
import pylab as py
from numpy.random import rand

x = rand(10)
y = rand(10)
p = py.gca()
p.plot(x,y, '.', label="x:y")

# other code, possibly a new cell in the notebook

a = rand(10)
b = rand(10)

p.plot(a,b, '--', label="a:b")
```

In fact in your original code, if you just removed the `p.` in your second plot command, you'd get what I think you were after.

Comment: To make this better, I would a) **avoid pylab**. Promulgating the use of pylab in scripting is not not not good (see [here](http://carreau.github.io/posts/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.ipynb.html)), and b) describe what the object you mention *actually is* (i.e., an `Axes` object)

Comment: Another question: how do I plot p from the above example elsewhere in the code? Is there a `p.show()` or something like that?

Comment: @ajean Can you recommend an alternative for the purposes of plotting things?  Your link doesn't seem to be saying don't use pylab, but rather don't import it in a certain way.  I'm not an expert, so I may not be interpreting it correctly.

Comment: @AlexanderFlyax There will be a way to do that, but not through `p.show()`.  `p` is an axes object sitting in a figure somewhere.  So you'll have to get ahold of the figure itself and show that figure.  (note, you won't be able to take those axes and put them into other figures easily).  This is at the edge of my comfort zone, so I'm going to pass on trying to answer.

Comment: @Joel, keep in mind that pylab != matplotlib. Pylab *includes* matplotlib, but it also does tons of other funny business behind the scenes. If you must, use matplotlib's pyplot interface (also != pylab). You should learn what the differences are between those three things, it will make your life easier in the long run!

Comment: @Ajean the link in your comment is dead

Comment: @hitzg Ok, thanks .... [here](http://carreau.github.io/posts/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.html) is the current one, although I'm not sure I want to bother keeping it up if ever it disappears completely.  Comments are inherently transient.

Comment: @Ajean Just to revisit this - I still don't see anything in that link that says actually having `import pylab as py` is bad.  It's stating that starting ipython with the pylab flag is bad; a very different thing as far as I can tell (basically with the pylab flag it did `from pylab import *`, which I agree does stuff behind the scenes).  Doing `import pylab as py` means those funny things going on behind the scenes need a `py.***` to be used before they affect anything.  I don't see any of the issues raised in the link as being relevant for the code I provided.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Joel You are right that most of the problems seen with pylab come with either the `*` import or the `--pylab` ipython option.  My intention was not to imply your code is bad, only to imply that it would just be *better* to not use pylab if you don't have to.  If you only want it for matplotlib, why import all the extra stuff?  It's good practice - I used pylab for awhile when I started, but as you graduate to more complicated programs where you'll be using matplotlib and numpy (and scipy, and pandas, and ... and ...), keeping your imports as minimal as possible becomes more important IMO.

Comment: @Joel I just think it's especially important to push new coders in any particular language in the best directions from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

One way that I have solved this issue is to create your figure and axis as follows:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
```

Set figure parameters as needed here and finally call show but with block=False

```
plt.show(block=False)
```

Then from other functions you can add to the same axis by using Matplotlibs plt.gca() function that returns the current or last clicked on axis by the user as follows (but dont create a new figure or axis) and using Matplotlibs draw() function:

```
plt.gca().plot([4,5,6],[4,5,6])
plt.draw()
```